# Where is the entry-point of the C code generating by pypy

Tags: python, c, entry-point, pypy

I'm using PyPy to translate some python code to C code. I wrote a very simple script as below:

```
def main():
    print "hello world!"

def entry_point(argv):
    main()
    return 0

def target(*args):
    return entry_point, None
```

Then I used `translate.py --source test.py`. It did generate C code successful. When I `make` those code, it generated a executable file `test-c`. However I cannot find the main function in those code using `grep`, so I'm wondering where is the entry-point of the code generating by pypy.
Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 2):

that's incorrect. Grep for pypy_g_entry_point. main() function is likely to be inlined in this example, so you won't get it. If you want it to be rendered use --inline-threshold=0 as a translation parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to use--inline-threshold=0 as a translation parameter as you said. However I still cannot find the main() function in the generated C code.

Comment: it would be called pypy_g_main and live in implement.c

Comment: Thank you, I think I've solved my problem somehow. The main function is macro defined as PYPY_MAIN_FUNCTION in the file main.h

Answer (score 1):

PyPy is probably not giving you a "main" function because you actually don't have an entry point in your Python code.  You should probably just add

```
main()
```

at the end of the file.